# Android BluetoothLE Disconnection issue

Tags: performance, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm rebuilding a ble app that will commnunicate with a bluetooth device.

The code I found had this odd method called after closing the connection,

```
bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
```

which will call the onStateChangeCallback.

The method is this;

```
 private void refreshDeviceCache(final BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    int cnt = 0;

    boolean success = false;

    try {
        if (gatt != null) {
            final Method refresh = gatt.getClass().getMethod("refresh");
            if (refresh != null) {
                success = (Boolean) refresh.invoke(gatt);

                while (!success && cnt < 100) {
                    success = (Boolean) refresh.invoke(gatt);
                    cnt++;
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "retry refresh : " + cnt + "   " + success);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "5", e);
    }
}
```

I can't totally understand what this code will do, but in conclusion, it slows down the **connection** after the disconnection. It does not slow down the disconnection.

I really can't understand this because after I get the BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED, I will close the bluetoothGatt, and on the broadCastReceiver, unbind the service and close the service itself.

On the connection phase, the service will be recreated.

What line of that code on disconnection may slow down the connection? Please help me out with this.